# Terminal, du file and awk

Tags: awk, terminal

I'm trying to print the names, the types and the sizes of all files and subdirectories, using du, file and awk in bash. my code so far is:

```
du -bsh * | awk '{print $2, $1}' ; file * | awk '{print $2}'
```

They run separately so they print separately. How do I make this as one command?

expected output:

```
File1             ASCII text          10K
Mov.mp4           ISO Media           15M
Pictures          directory           4,0K
bder.c            C source            4,6K
```

Comment: Not clear, could you please mention expected output in your post in code tags and let us know then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{infos[$1]=$2}NR!=FNR{print $2, infos[$2 ":"], $1}' OFS="\t" <(file *) <(du -bsh *)
```

Awk reads the output of `file *` first.
It runs `NR==FNR{infos[$1]=$2}` and stores the informations inside the associative array `infos`.

Then awk reads the output of `du -bsh *` and executes this block `NR!=FNR{print $2, infos[$2 ":"], $1}'`.

Read [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to learn more about process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in a solution like this:

```
paste <(stat -c "%n %s" *) <(file -b *)
```

or if you like your output a bit cleaner:

```
paste -d'|' <(stat -c "%n|%s" *) <(file -b *) | column -s"|" -t
```

which gives you the following output:

```
File1      10240       ASCII text
Mov.mp4    15728640    ISO Media
Pictures   4096        directory
bder.c     4710        C source
```